# Angular JS Fetching Information in Backgroud using $timeout or $interval Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I am trying to fetch information from webapi in background using $timeout or $interval service.

I have a question regarding $timeout or $interval Service in Angular JS.
I have experienced some issues when using these services, When we inject any of these services in our controller.
Following are my observations from my current development :
 - There are multiple nested controllers in application.
 - When we tried to move from one state to another, $timeout or $interval service invoked again.
   (This is can avoided by canceling timer on Scope Destroy)
 - But what about maintaining timer information.

Can we create service or factory to achieve this ?

Comment: Without more information on what your $timeouts and $intervals are doing: yes, you can.

Comment: @JanS
Hello, i am currently working on pulling latest data from Api Server.
There is 5 minute interval for every api request.
But when i go from one state to another timer is invoked again.
Note : That timer code is written in first parent controller.

Comment: Do you have any code snippet for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a factory for this. This will instantiate the $timeout and $interval only once.

By setting up a factory like the one below, you can share data retrieved/created from within an $interval with your controller (see bottom):

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('interval', interval);

interval.$inject = ['$interval'];

function interval($interval) {
  var counter = {};
  activate();

  return {
    counter: counter
  };

  function activate() {
    $interval(increaseCounter, 1000);
  }

  function increaseCounter() {
    if(angular.isUndefined(counter.count)) {
      counter.count = 0;
    } else {
      counter.count++;
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the controller:

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('TestController', testController);

testController.$inject = ['interval'];

function testController(interval) {
  var vm = this;
  this.counter = interval.counter;
}
```

Now you can display the counter (or whatever data you get from your $interval) in the view:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController as ctrl">
  {{ctrl.counter.count}}
</div>
```

Important to notice is, that you can't share `count` directly. This is because of how JavaScript deals with passing values by reference/value.

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m5hw5w1o/

Comment: This solution worked for me.
It is helpful for developer like me.